# How to convert byte array contained in object to actual image?

Tags: casting

I  am developing smart device application in C#. In that I am calling the web services. The web service method return google map. The return type of the method is object. The object contains the image in byte format. The object conatins the image in base64binary format. In object I am not getting the string. In object I am getting the byte array. I need to display the actual image in my application. What type of casting I need to do to display the image. Can you provide me the code or any link through which I can resolve the above issue?

Comment: didn't you just ask this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346436/how-to-convert-object-which-receives-image-in-bytes-into-actual-image

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346436/how-to-convert-object-which-receives-image-in-bytes-into-actual-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Graphics::Bitmap object

then you have to associate your byte array to the data pointer inside that class

[Here is an example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ShrutiShrivastava/ImageProcessing12192005061519AM/ImageProcessing.aspx)