# Convert Object To Image

Tags: c#, .net, image, object

```
StudentPicture.BackgroundImage = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["studentPictureDataGridViewImageColumn"].Value;
```

How can I convert an object to an image?

Comment: You need to provide more information on what your data is and what you want to do.

Comment: Cast object, and use this `StudentPicture.BackgroundImage = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["studentPictureDataGridViewImageColumn"].Value as System.Drawing.Image;`

Answer (score -1):

Try converting your object to byte array. Then using [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netframework-4.8) to convert byte array to Image.

Quoted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346436/how-to-convert-object-which-receives-image-in-bytes-into-actual-image) post

```
byte[] yourImage;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image);
Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what format the object is in. It's just an object reference no matter if that reference is to an array or to a Bitmap object. This does not answer the question at all.